# Create a table from dataframe column values mean and standard deviation in R

Tags: r, function, max, mean, min

I am new to R so no idea about the code. I have two data frames. One dataframe looks like this.

###### df

| ID | Disease |
| --- | --- |
| GSM239170 | Control |
| GSM239323 | Control |
| GSM239324 | Control |
| GSM239326 | Control |
| GSM239328 | AML |
| GSM239329 | AML |
| GSM239331 | AML |
| GSM239332 | Control |
| GSM239333 | Control |

And the other dataframe looks like this:

###### df1

| GSM239170 | GSM239323 | GSM239324 | GSM239326 | GSM239328 | GSM239329 | GSM239331 | GSM239332 | GSM239333 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.016704177 | 3.285669072 | 2.929482692 | 2.922820483 | 3.15950317 | 3.163327169 | 2.985901308 | 3.122708843 | 3.070948463 |
| 7.977735461 | 6.532514237 | 6.388007183 | 6.466679556 | 6.432795021 | 6.407321524 | 6.426470803 | 6.376394357 | 6.469070308 |
| 4.207280707 | 4.994965767 | 4.40159671 | 4.747114589 | 4.830045513 | 4.213762092 | 4.884418365 | 4.4318876 | 4.849665444 |
| 7.25609471 | 7.420807337 | 6.999340125 | 7.094488581 | 7.024332721 | 7.17928981 | 7.159898654 | 7.009977785 | 6.830979234 |
| 2.204955099 | 2.331625217 | 2.133305231 | 2.18332885 | 2.12778313 | 2.269697813 | 2.264705552 | 2.253940441 | 2.287924323 |
| 7.28437278 | 6.983593721 | 6.86337111 | 6.865970678 | 7.219840938 | 7.181113053 | 7.392230178 | 7.484052914 | 7.52498281 |
| 4.265792764 | 4.970684112 | 4.595545125 | 4.575545289 | 4.547957809 | 4.68215122 | 4.674495889 | 4.675841709 | 4.643311767 |
| 2.6943516 | 2.916324936 | 2.578130269 | 2.659717988 | 2.567436676 | 2.8095128 | 2.790110381 | 2.795882913 | 2.884588792 |
| 3.646303109 | 8.817891552 | 11.4248793 | 10.74738082 | 9.296043108 | 9.53150669 | 8.285160496 | 9.769919327 | 9.774610531 |
| 3.040292001 | 3.38486713 | 2.958851115 | 3.047880699 | 2.878562717 | 3.209319974 | 3.20260379 | 3.195993624 | 3.3004227 |
| 2.357625231 | 2.444753172 | 2.340767158 | 2.32143889 | 2.282608342 | 2.401218719 | 2.385568421 | 2.375334953 | 2.432634747 |
| 5.378494673 | 6.065038394 | 5.134842087 | 5.367342376 | 5.682051149 | 5.712072512 | 5.57179966 | 5.72082395 | 5.656674512 |
| 2.833814735 | 3.038434511 | 2.837711812 | 2.859800224 | 2.866040813 | 2.969167906 | 2.929449968 | 2.963530689 | 2.931065261 |
| 6.192932281 | 6.478439634 | 6.180169144 | 6.151689376 | 6.238949956 | 6.708196123 | 6.441437631 | 6.448280595 | 6.413562269 |
| 4.543042482 | 4.786227217 | 4.445131477 | 4.51471011 | 4.491645167 | 4.460114204 | 4.602482637 | 4.587221948 | 4.623125028 |
| 6.069437462 | 6.232738284 | 6.74644117 | 7.04995802 | 6.938928532 | 6.348253102 | 6.080950712 | 6.324619355 | 6.472893789 |

I want to make a table to include mean_AML, sd_AML (standard deviation), min_AML, max_AML, mean_Control, sd_Control, min_Control, max_Control, and Fold_change (i.e, mean_AML – mean_Control) for each gene. It is fine to use built-in functions.

Can't figure out the way how I can do this. Please help.

Thanks.

#### --- UPDATE ---

Hints: split the dataset into AML data and normal data sets, and then for each gene/probeset, calculate its mean, standard derivation, min and max expression values across samples separately (using a built-in function), and further merge these statistical values for each gene into one table. Apply data.frame() and give the created table the same row names as the gene expression data table.

Comment: i don't know, i posted the question as it is. There is no other explanation for fold change

Comment: How I can find the foldchange anyway?

Comment: I have included a function which gives you the fold changes acccording to the `mean` and `median`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option with old function `tidyr::gather` to have a column df:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2_spread <- df1 %>% 
  tidyr::gather(ID, val) %>% 
  left_join(df, by = 'ID')
  
result_1 <- df2_spread %>% 
  group_by(Disease, gene = ID) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(),
            mean = mean(val),
            sd = sd(val),
            min = min(val),
            max = max(val), .groups = "drop")
```

```
 A tibble: 9 × 7
  Disease gene          n  mean    sd   min   max
  <chr>   <chr>     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 AML     GSM239328    16  4.91  2.15  2.13  9.30
2 AML     GSM239329    16  4.95  2.13  2.27  9.53
3 AML     GSM239331    16  4.88  1.96  2.26  8.29
4 Control GSM239170    16  4.56  1.91  2.20  7.98
5 Control GSM239323    16  5.04  1.98  2.33  8.82
6 Control GSM239324    16  4.93  2.45  2.13 11.4 
7 Control GSM239326    16  4.97  2.34  2.18 10.7 
8 Control GSM239332    16  4.97  2.16  2.25  9.77
9 Control GSM239333    16  5.01  2.14  2.29  9.77
```

In any case I'm not able to find a way to calculate Fold_change for each gene since there seems to be only one disease by gene here.

Here are the datas

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
          ~ID,  ~Disease,
  "GSM239170", "Control",
  "GSM239323", "Control",
  "GSM239324", "Control",
  "GSM239326", "Control",
  "GSM239328",     "AML",
  "GSM239329",     "AML",
  "GSM239331",     "AML",
  "GSM239332", "Control",
  "GSM239333", "Control"
  )



df1 <- tibble::tribble(
   ~GSM239170,  ~GSM239323,  ~GSM239324,  ~GSM239326,  ~GSM239328,  ~GSM239329,  ~GSM239331,  ~GSM239332,  ~GSM239333,
  3.016704177, 3.285669072, 2.929482692, 2.922820483,  3.15950317, 3.163327169, 2.985901308, 3.122708843, 3.070948463,
  7.977735461, 6.532514237, 6.388007183, 6.466679556, 6.432795021, 6.407321524, 6.426470803, 6.376394357, 6.469070308,
  4.207280707, 4.994965767,  4.40159671, 4.747114589, 4.830045513, 4.213762092, 4.884418365,   4.4318876, 4.849665444,
   7.25609471, 7.420807337, 6.999340125, 7.094488581, 7.024332721,  7.17928981, 7.159898654, 7.009977785, 6.830979234,
  2.204955099, 2.331625217, 2.133305231,  2.18332885,  2.12778313, 2.269697813, 2.264705552, 2.253940441, 2.287924323,
   7.28437278, 6.983593721,  6.86337111, 6.865970678, 7.219840938, 7.181113053, 7.392230178, 7.484052914,  7.52498281,
  4.265792764, 4.970684112, 4.595545125, 4.575545289, 4.547957809,  4.68215122, 4.674495889, 4.675841709, 4.643311767,
    2.6943516, 2.916324936, 2.578130269, 2.659717988, 2.567436676,   2.8095128, 2.790110381, 2.795882913, 2.884588792,
  3.646303109, 8.817891552,  11.4248793, 10.74738082, 9.296043108,  9.53150669, 8.285160496, 9.769919327, 9.774610531,
  3.040292001,  3.38486713, 2.958851115, 3.047880699, 2.878562717, 3.209319974,  3.20260379, 3.195993624,   3.3004227,
  2.357625231, 2.444753172, 2.340767158,  2.32143889, 2.282608342, 2.401218719, 2.385568421, 2.375334953, 2.432634747,
  5.378494673, 6.065038394, 5.134842087, 5.367342376, 5.682051149, 5.712072512,  5.57179966,  5.72082395, 5.656674512,
  2.833814735, 3.038434511, 2.837711812, 2.859800224, 2.866040813, 2.969167906, 2.929449968, 2.963530689, 2.931065261,
  6.192932281, 6.478439634, 6.180169144, 6.151689376, 6.238949956, 6.708196123, 6.441437631, 6.448280595, 6.413562269,
  4.543042482, 4.786227217, 4.445131477,  4.51471011, 4.491645167, 4.460114204, 4.602482637, 4.587221948, 4.623125028,
  6.069437462, 6.232738284,  6.74644117,  7.04995802, 6.938928532, 6.348253102, 6.080950712, 6.324619355, 6.472893789
  )
```

Comment: Error: Join columns must be present in data.

Comment: Ok, I edit answer to give you df and df1 raw data and column names (for which it works for me).

Comment: How to save this tibble that is created by %>%

Comment: I have edited to create result_1 data.frame with `<-` assignment operator. If you have to save it in excel, it's also possible, let me know

Answer (score 1):

We could combine `pivot_longer` with `right_join` and then use `summarise` on the group:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = "ID", 
    values_to = "value"
  ) %>% 
  right_join(df, by="ID") %>% 
  group_by(Disease) %>% 
  summarise(Min = min(value), Mean = mean(value), Max = max(value), Sd = sd(value)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
  Disease   Min  Mean   Max    Sd
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 AML      2.13  4.91  9.53  2.04
2 Control  2.13  4.92 11.4   2.12
```

Comment: Error: Can't combine `ID` <character> and `GSM239170` <double>.

Comment: In your df  and df1, there is no `Probe_ID`?!

Comment: There is SampleID

Comment: Why the code is not working for me? The original names of df are SampleID and Disease_status instead of ID and Disease. When I do ```right_join(df, by="SampleID") %>% 
  group_by(Disease_status) %>% ``` I got the error, ```Error: Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `SampleID`.```

Comment: Change `names_to = 'SampleID` within `pivot_longer(...) above `right_join()`

Comment: How I can find fold change by applying this formula ```fc = mean_AML – mean_Control```

Answer (score 0):

It will help to put the second dataframe in long format using `pivot_longer()`:

```
library(tidyr)
newdf <- pivot_longer(df1, 
    cols = everything(),
    names_to = 'ID',
    values_to = 'value')
```

Then `merge()` the two dataframes into one:

```
df.all <- merge(df, newdf, by = 'ID', all = T)
```

Then you can `group_by(gene)` and `summarise()`, adding whatever values you need:

```
library(dplyr)
df.all %>% group_by(gene) %>% summarise(sd = sd(value), min = min(value), max = max(value), mean = mean(value))
```

Comment: Error: Can't combine `Probe_ID` <character> and `GSM239170` <double>.

Comment: @Zaif You should convert each ID column into a factor using as.factor(). I suspect this error is coming from the merge function?

Answer (score 0):

A **base R** approach.

```
df_new <- data.frame(t(df1), ID=colnames(df1))
df_new <- merge(df, df_new, by = 'ID')
out <- apply(df_new[, grep('^X', names(df_new))], 1, function(x) {
    data.frame(min=min(x), IQR_low=quantile(x, .25),
          mean=mean(x), median=median(x),IQR_high=quantile(x, .75),
          max=max(x), sd=sd(x))
})
out <- round(do.call(rbind, out), 2L)
out <- cbind(Disease=df_new$Disease, out)
rownames(out) <- df_new$ID
```

**Output**

```
> out
          Disease  min IQR_low mean median IQR_high   max   sd
GSM239170 Control 2.20    2.97 4.56   4.24     6.10  7.98 1.91
GSM239323 Control 2.33    3.22 5.04   4.98     6.49  8.82 1.98
GSM239324 Control 2.13    2.91 4.93   4.52     6.48 11.42 2.45
GSM239326 Control 2.18    2.91 4.97   4.66     6.57 10.75 2.34
GSM239328     AML 2.13    2.88 4.91   4.69     6.56  9.30 2.15
GSM239329     AML 2.27    3.11 4.95   4.57     6.48  9.53 2.13
GSM239331     AML 2.26    2.97 4.88   4.78     6.43  8.29 1.96
GSM239332 Control 2.25    3.08 4.97   4.63     6.39  9.77 2.16
GSM239333 Control 2.29    3.04 5.01   4.75     6.47  9.77 2.14
```

Now we need to find all 18 fold changes, which you defined as mean_AML - mean_Control. This can be done with the following function, `fold_change_fun()`, which returns the fold changes according to the `mean` or `median`.

```
fold_change_fun <- function(x, statistic = c('mean', 'median')) {
  AML_genes <- rownames(x[x$Disease %in% 'AML', ])
  Control_genes <- rownames(x[x$Disease %in% 'Control', ])
  AML <- x[x$Disease %in% 'AML', statistic]
  Control <- x[x$Disease %in% 'Control', statistic]
  nrow_AML <- nrow(out[out$Disease %in% 'AML', ])
  nrow_Control <- nrow(out[out$Disease %in% 'Control', ])
  out <- matrix(c(prod(nrow_AML, nrow_Control)),
                nrow = nrow_AML, ncol = nrow_Control)
  for(i in seq_len(nrow_AML)) {
    for(j in seq_len(nrow_Control)) {
      out[i, j] <- AML[i] - Control[j]
    }
  }
  out <- t(out)
  colnames(out) <- paste(AML_genes, 'AML')
  rownames(out) <- paste(Control_genes, 'Control')
  return(out)
}
```

**Output**

```
> fold_change_fun(x = out, statistic = 'mean')
                  GSM239328 AML GSM239329 AML GSM239331 AML
GSM239170 Control          0.35          0.39          0.32
GSM239323 Control         -0.13         -0.09         -0.16
GSM239324 Control         -0.02          0.02         -0.05
GSM239326 Control         -0.06         -0.02         -0.09
GSM239332 Control         -0.06         -0.02         -0.09
GSM239333 Control         -0.10         -0.06         -0.13

> fold_change_fun(x = out, statistic = 'median')
                  GSM239328 AML GSM239329 AML GSM239331 AML
GSM239170 Control          0.45          0.33          0.54
GSM239323 Control         -0.29         -0.41         -0.20
GSM239324 Control          0.17          0.05          0.26
GSM239326 Control          0.03         -0.09          0.12
GSM239332 Control          0.06         -0.06          0.15
GSM239333 Control         -0.06         -0.18          0.03
```

Note that these are simply point estimates. We do not know how precise these sample fold changes are as estimators of the population fold changes.

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("GSM239170", "GSM239323", "GSM239324", 
"GSM239326", "GSM239328", "GSM239329", "GSM239331", "GSM239332", 
"GSM239333"), Disease = c("Control", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"AML", "AML", "AML", "Control", "Control")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")

df1 <- structure(list(GSM239170 = c(3.016704177, 7.977735461, 4.207280707, 
7.25609471, 2.204955099, 7.28437278, 4.265792764, 2.6943516, 
3.646303109, 3.040292001, 2.357625231, 5.378494673, 2.833814735, 
6.192932281, 4.543042482, 6.069437462), GSM239323 = c(3.285669072, 
6.532514237, 4.994965767, 7.420807337, 2.331625217, 6.983593721, 
4.970684112, 2.916324936, 8.817891552, 3.38486713, 2.444753172, 
6.065038394, 3.038434511, 6.478439634, 4.786227217, 6.232738284
), GSM239324 = c(2.929482692, 6.388007183, 4.40159671, 6.999340125, 
2.133305231, 6.86337111, 4.595545125, 2.578130269, 11.4248793, 
2.958851115, 2.340767158, 5.134842087, 2.837711812, 6.180169144, 
4.445131477, 6.74644117), GSM239326 = c(2.922820483, 6.466679556, 
4.747114589, 7.094488581, 2.18332885, 6.865970678, 4.575545289, 
2.659717988, 10.74738082, 3.047880699, 2.32143889, 5.367342376, 
2.859800224, 6.151689376, 4.51471011, 7.04995802), GSM239328 = c(3.15950317, 
6.432795021, 4.830045513, 7.024332721, 2.12778313, 7.219840938, 
4.547957809, 2.567436676, 9.296043108, 2.878562717, 2.282608342, 
5.682051149, 2.866040813, 6.238949956, 4.491645167, 6.938928532
), GSM239329 = c(3.163327169, 6.407321524, 4.213762092, 7.17928981, 
2.269697813, 7.181113053, 4.68215122, 2.8095128, 9.53150669, 
3.209319974, 2.401218719, 5.712072512, 2.969167906, 6.708196123, 
4.460114204, 6.348253102), GSM239331 = c(2.985901308, 6.426470803, 
4.884418365, 7.159898654, 2.264705552, 7.392230178, 4.674495889, 
2.790110381, 8.285160496, 3.20260379, 2.385568421, 5.57179966, 
2.929449968, 6.441437631, 4.602482637, 6.080950712), GSM239332 = c(3.122708843, 
6.376394357, 4.4318876, 7.009977785, 2.253940441, 7.484052914, 
4.675841709, 2.795882913, 9.769919327, 3.195993624, 2.375334953, 
5.72082395, 2.963530689, 6.448280595, 4.587221948, 6.324619355
), GSM239333 = c(3.070948463, 6.469070308, 4.849665444, 6.830979234, 
2.287924323, 7.52498281, 4.643311767, 2.884588792, 9.774610531, 
3.3004227, 2.432634747, 5.656674512, 2.931065261, 6.413562269, 
4.623125028, 6.472893789)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Getting the error ```Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

Comment: Have you tried it on the data that I provided above?

Comment: Resolved this error by renaming column. But got this error in next code line. ```Error in (1 - h) * qs[i] : non-numeric argument to binary operator``` This error is in ```out <- apply(df_new[, grep('^X', names(df_new))], 1, function(x) ..... ``` line

Comment: on your data, yes it is working. On my big data, not working

Comment: The error you describe is because you are trying to apply a mathematical function onto something thats not numeric. Check whether the 16 genes are indeed numeric by looking at their structure with something like `str(df1[, grep('^GSM[[:digit:]]', names(df1))])`.

Comment: running this command gave me this: ```'data.frame': 22283 obs. of  64 variables:
 $ GSM239170: num  3.02 7.98 4.21 7.26 2.2 ...
 $ GSM239323: num  3.29 6.53 4.99 7.42 2.33 ...
 $ GSM239324: num  2.93 6.39 4.4 7 2.13 ...```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `str(df_new[, grep('^X[[:digit:]]', names(df_new))])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241266/discussion-between-zaif-and-dion-groothof).